# Calculate angle required to hit coordinate (x,y) from position other than (0,0) with varying elevation

Tags: c#, xna, physics, trigonometry

I am attempting to calculate the angle required to fire a projectile in order to hit a specific coordinate.

My projectile is located a random coordinate and my target coordinate at a static coordinate.

I ended up running across the following equation on Wikipedia for calculating the angle required to hit a coordinate at (x,y) from (0,0):

[image]

I have made some attempts to understand this and other formula and attempted the following implementation (I am using c# and XNA).

```
double y = source.Y - target.Y;
double x = Vector2.Distance(source, target);
double v = 1440; //velocity
double g = 25; //gravity
double sqrt = (v*v*v*v) - (g*(g*(x*x) + 2*y*(v*v)));
sqrt = Math.Sqrt(sqrt);
double angleInRadians = Math.Atan(((v*v) + sqrt)/(g*x));
```

I have also attempted the following, which resulted in an identical angle where the values of v and g remain the same.

```
double targetX = target.X - source.X;
double targetY = -(target.Y - source.Y);
double r1 = Math.Sqrt((v*v*v*v) - g*(g*(target.X*target.X) + ((2*target.Y)*(v*v))));
double a1 = ((v*v) + r1)/(g*target.X);
angleInRadians = -Math.Atan(a1);
if (targetX < 0)
{
    angleInRadians -= 180/180*Math.PI;
}
```

My conjecture is that even in my (assumed) attempt to zero out the source coordinate, that I am still not performing the calculation correctly for coordinates with a non (0,0) source and different elevations.

Below is an image that depicts my coordinate system.  It is the default for XNA.

[image]

Comment: I think you should translate your actual positions to (0,0)-based system, perform the function there and perform a final translation from (0,0) to actual system...assuming there are no factors other than gravity, Angle calculated should be the same from any source...

Comment: What are the other parameters (input) that affects the projectile path, like is the velocity and gravity constants or what other variables are there ?

Comment: Isn't gravity supposed to be negative? It's -9.8m/s if I recall correctly.

Comment: I will give that a try @boxed__l.  You are correct that gravity is the only factor.

Comment: @Sniffer the inputs are a source coordinate, target coordinate, a constant initial velocity of 1440m/s, a constant gravity of 25m/s.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineault you are correct, my value should be negative.  I have a non real world gravity constant of 25m/s.  I was compensating for this value not being negative by using the negative of Math.Sin(angleInRadians) to flip the Y value of the angle as a vector over.  I have corrected this.

Comment: @boxed__l That ended up doing the trick.  I changed x and y to be the following x = -(source.x - target.x), y = (source.y - target.y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help in the comments the solution to find this angle ended up requiring that the positions be translated to a (0,0) based system.  For anyone looking for the same scenario the final working solution was:

```
double x = -(source.x - target.x);
double y = (source.y - target.y);
double v = 1440; //m/s
double g = 25; //m/s
double sqrt = (v*v*v*v) - (g*(g*(x*x) + 2*y*(v*v)));
sqrt = Math.Sqrt(sqrt);
angleInRadians = Math.Atan(((v*v) + sqrt)/(g*x));
```

Then to convert the radians into a vector that works with XNA, perform the following conversion:

```
Vector2 angleVector = new Vector2(-(float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians), (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians));
```

Comment: For the record, if anyone else comes across this and finds it useful: The return value is a normalized vector. In my case, I only had to scale it with projectile muzzle velocity. using Java/libgdx: `return angleVector.scl((float)RifleBullet.projectileSpeed);`

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem lies in the use of arctan. Because the range is limited to -pi/2..pi/2 results are only in the right half plane.

Use arctan2 to get the proper coordinates:

```
angleInRadians = Math.Atan2(((v*v) + tmp), (g*x));
```